# How Can I Turn Excel Function Into VBA Code?

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

I am looking to convert an Excel function into VBA code to work in a button but am having some trouble as I am new to coding. I have tried looking up code that would multiply cells and do what I need it to but have had no luck implementing them into my code. Below is the function that I am trying to turn into code. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

=SUM(G17-(G16*0.65))

```
Public Function Sum()

Range("G17").Value -Range("G16").Value * 0.65

End Function
```

Comment: `Range("G17").Value - Range("G16").Value * 0.65`?

Comment: BTW: `=SUM(G17-(G16*0.65))` is the same as `=G17-G16*0.65` with less typing.

Comment: Always helps to show the code you tried, even if it's not working.

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include the code.

Comment: `code` Public Function Sum()

Range("G17").Value -Range("G16").Value * 0.65

End Function

Comment: You can't/shouldn't name a UDF with the same name as a built-in worksheet function

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to replace Excel WorkSheet function by your own VBA function, this is excellent to develop complicated UDF to use in your VBA projects.

First you should create a Public Module, named for example `basMyModule`.

In this module you add this code

```
Option Explicit

Function mySum()

  mySum = Range("G17").Value - Range("G16").Value * 0.65

End Function
```

The keyword Public is implicit in a global module, so useless.
At the end of the function you assign `mySum` to the value to return in VBA.

Now `mySum`() is a function you can use in an Excel cell, replacing Worksheet function Sum() like this:

```
=mySum()
```